# How does this Tensor Product basis example is made up?

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products

Here is a link for the [article.](http://hitoshi.berkeley.edu/221a/tensorproduct.pdf) On page 5 of 14 author is talking about *tensor product* befor that he explains *direct sum* and does it very clearly by stacking vectors on top of each over. But here (the picture) I just don't understand how he got that basis! What is the mechanics of such a "stacking/shuffling"?

[image: Here is a picture from an article:]

Any help with clear examples of the same type of tensor product will be much appreciated.

Comment: Why are the basis vectors represented by those column vectors? Because the author felt like doing it that way. That's really all there is to it. If you wanted a more generally applicable procedure, for conciseness it'd make more sense to use $m\times n$ matrices (via Kronecker product of column vectors), but of course you can always represent $m\times n$ matrices with $mn$-length column vectors by "stacking" the matrices' columns one atop the other (as you observe).

Comment: Well, I guess you can make alot of "representations" of a tensor product but I'm right now interested in this particular representation. I haven't been able to find any easier explanation of the subject yet. So I ask about this particular case. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's called the [Kroenecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product), and it is a concrete way to construct the tensor product of matrices (tensor products are usually quite abstract). In this case, you get
$$
\vec e_1\otimes \vec f_1 = \begin{pmatrix}1\cdot \vec e_1\\0\cdot\vec e_1\end{pmatrix}
$$
where the $1$ and $0$ are the components of $\vec f_1$. This works as well as can be expected for matrices, and you get nice properties like $(AB)\otimes (CD) = (A \otimes C)(B\otimes D)$ (as long as the dimensions fit together, like, for instance, if $A$ is a linear combination of $\vec e_i$'s, $C$ is a combination of $\vec f_i$'s, $C$ is $3\times 3$ and $D$ is $2 \times 2$).

Comment: Ok, so in your interpretation vector e→1⊗f→1 is a vector over vector space (not over field R)? I mean the "coordinates" are not scalars any more but vectors themselves?

Comment: @coobit In a sense, yes, $\vec e_i\otimes \vec f_j$ are the basis vectors in $(\Bbb R^3)^2$. That's what the vertical line in the column vectors in your textbook means.